# weird 20 ef bb bf added by Wordpress on main (index.php) page

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I'm writing a WordPress template from scratch.

I've written a header.php page like:

```
       <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
...
<head>
<body>
<header>...</header>
```

and so on.
The index.php goes like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Running the site I've seen a weird blank line on top of my page.

I've tried to use the same identical code on page.php, and the white line wasn't there!

The two generated HTML looked identical, excepted for the title. Changing it, the white line remained.

I've then downloaded the two pages on an hex editor and ta-da! on the main website page, `<!doctype html>` was preceded by these hex values (which are a space and  UTF BOM as I understand)

```
20 ef bb bf
```

while the page had only the space

```
20
```

the ef bb bf part was the culprit! If I save the index.htm file the white gap still remains, if I cut the three chars and resave and reopen, the white gap disappears.

So, Wordpress seems to add, ONLY on the main page and not on a page.php generated page, that header which completely breaks my rendered html.

worse: the 20 ef bb bf header shows even if I put only html in index.php.

how can I get rid of it?

thanks

Comment: What editor did you use to write the page?

Comment: @Diamondo25 I've used Sublimetext2 on windows, but I've used it both for index.php AND page.php (and for header.php too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and rewriting  index.php from scratch solved the problem. Most probably, somehow, SublimeText wrote those headers in my file.